# Cut and Awk command in linux

Tags: linux, awk, cut

How can I extract word between 2 words in a file using cut and awk command.

Lets say: I have a file with below content.

This is my file and it has lots of content along wiht password and want to extract PASSWORD=MYPASSWORDISHERE==and file is ending here.

**exptected output**

1) using awk command linux.
2) using cut command linux.

```
MYPASSWORDISHERE==
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` actually `gawk`

```
awk '{match($0,/PASSWORD=(.*==)/,a); print a[1];}' input.txt
```

Using `cut` you can try, I'm not sure if it works with your file

```
cut -d"=" -s -f2,3 --output-delimiter="==" input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... :) You saved my lot of time. Thank.